# golang Couchbase n1ql query pass params to?

Tags: go, couchbase

I'm trying to find a way to pass parameters to query, but not quite sure how. The API on the [web site](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/sdks/go-beta/querying.html) looks a little bit outdated?

```
myQuery := gocb.NewN1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM default")
rows, err := myBucket.ExecuteN1qlQuery(myQuery)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("N1QL query error: %s\n", err)
}
var row interface{}
for rows.Next(&row) {
    fmt.Printf("Row: %+v\n", row)
}
if err := rows.Close(); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("N1QL query error: %s\n", err)
}
```

Because, actually ExecuteN1qlQuery takes two params:

```
func (b *Bucket) ExecuteN1qlQuery(q *N1qlQuery, params interface{}) (ViewResults, error)
```

I am not sure just how to use it... Like I would like to create a query with placeholders, and pass values to  ExecuteN1qlQuery via params. Like with SQL (prepare -> execute). For example something like that:

```
    myQuery := gocb.NewN1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM default where a=? and b=?")
    rows, err := myBucket.ExecuteN1qlQuery(myQuery,[]string{"b","c"})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("N1QL query error: %s\n", err)
    }
    var row interface{}
    for rows.Next(&row) {
        fmt.Printf("Row: %+v\n", row)
    }
    if err := rows.Close(); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("N1QL query error: %s\n", err)
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example you posted for how to do do this is from our developer guide repo on github:

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/devguide-examples/blob/master/go/query-placeholders.go.

Basically, you're using $ which references an interface and a corresponding positional parameter beginning with 1.

For your example it would look something like:

```
// Setup a new query with a placeholder
myQuery := gocb.NewN1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM default where a=$1 and b=$2")

// Setup an array for parameters
var myParams []interface{}
myParams = append(myParams,"foo")
myParams = append(myParams,"bar")

// Execute Query
rows, err := bucket.ExecuteN1qlQuery(myQuery, myParams)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("ERROR EXECUTING N1QL QUERY:", err)
}

// Iterate through rows and print output
var row interface{}
for rows.Next(&row) {
    fmt.Printf("Results: %+v\n", row)
}
```

Comment: Do you think my link to the repo was not good enough? :-)
This example solved all problems I had. 
The problem was to find the example, it was not quite straight way, may be because I was expected more from couchbase  site

Comment: Mike, we are constantly working to improve the documentation--especially the dev guide.  Thanks for posting this question.

Answer (score 0):

Just [found example](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/devguide-examples/blob/master/go/query-placeholders.go)

```
        myQuery := gocb.NewN1qlQuery("SELECT airportname, city, country FROM `travel-sample` " +
        "WHERE type='airport' AND city=$1 ")

    // Setup an array for parameters
    var myParams []interface{}
    myParams = append(myParams, "Reno")

    // Execute Query
    rows, err := bucket.ExecuteN1qlQuery(myQuery, myParams)
```